# static void Main method for codility test

Tags: c#, .net

When I run the program without using a static method it was saying that...

> Running solution...
>   Compilation successful.
>   Example test:   [-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1] 
>   OK 
>   Your code is syntactically correct and works properly on the example test.

When I used the static method...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int difference = new  Solution().solution(new int[] { -1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1});
        Console.WriteLine(difference);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I was getting error...

> Running solution...
>   Compiler output:
>   Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
>   user.cs(16,24): error CS0017: Program `user.exe' has more than one entry point defined:`SolutionWrapper.Main(string[])'
>   Solution.cs(40,17): error CS0017: Program `user.exe' has more than one entry point defined:`Solution.Main(string[])'
>   Detected some errors.

I was looking at the Tape-Equilibrium challenge and this is what I was trying to do and if I remove static void method there are no errors....

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int difference = new  Program().solution(new int[] { -1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1});
        Console.WriteLine(difference);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public int solution(int[] A)
    {
        // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
        var length = A.Length;

        if (length == 1) return A[0];
        if (length == 2) return Math.Abs(A[0] - A[1]);

        var leftSum = 0;
        var rightSum = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            rightSum += A[i];
        }

        var difference = int.MaxValue;

        for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        {
            var value = A[i];

            leftSum += value;
            rightSum -= value;

            difference = Math.Min(difference, Math.Abs(rightSum - leftSum));

            if (difference == 0) return 0;
        }

        return difference;
    }
```

Is static method not to be used then?

Comment: Do you have 2 `Main` methods? its not allowed.

Comment: One method is generated for me and it was public int solution(int[] A) { //code here }

Comment: what i mean is, in your whole code, do you have more than 1 `public static void Main(string[] args)` method definitions. Irrespective of which class they are in? This is not allowed. Any program can have only 1 entry point. `Main` method is this entry point. you have 2, where will the program start its execution from?

Comment: @singsuyash - I have updated with additional information. I have one method as static void Main(string[] args). I have also tried public static void Main (string[] args)

Answer (score 1):

Do like this... It will work.

```
using System;

class Solution {
  public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
    var length = A.Length;

    if (length == 1) return A[0];
    if (length == 2) return Math.Abs(A[0] - A[1]);

    var leftSum = 0;
    var rightSum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        rightSum += A[i];
    }

    var difference = int.MaxValue;

    for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
        var value = A[i];

        leftSum += value;
        rightSum -= value;

        difference = Math.Min(difference, Math.Abs(rightSum - leftSum));

        if (difference == 0) return 0;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(difference);
    return difference;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as you have two `static public void Main()`'s defined in your code.

As one is auto-generated, you may not be able to easily remove it. You can work around this by either setting the startup object for your project in the project properties > Application settings, or - if building manually - using the `/main` compiler option to specify the path to the `Main` you want as your entry point.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Does that mean we *can* have 2 `Main` methods?

Comment: @David Arno - If I use public int solution(int[] A) and leave out the static void Main(string[] args) will I not pass the test?

Comment: @singsuyash, you can ... it doesn't mean you should though! :)

Comment: @Person, specify *your* main as the entry point to run your tests. Only do this if you can't remove the auto-generated one though. It's better to just have the one `Main`.